# How to automatically add slug according to username of a user in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to django. Currenty I am trying to make social network website. Here is my model of profile class. I want to assign value of slug field to the username of the User. But can't find or think of any way to do this.
If anyone know any way of doing this I'll be thankfull if you suggest me how to do this

````
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER = [
        ('NONE', 'none'),
        ('MALE', 'male'),
        ('FEMALE', 'female')
    ]
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='No bio data', max_length=400)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    gerder = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, default='NONE')
    country = CountryField()
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='avatars/')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True, related_name='friends')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, blank = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    favourite = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-{self.created}'

    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out that using this in profile class will automatically assign username of the user

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this is my final profile class

````
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER = [
        ('NONE', 'none'),
        ('MALE', 'male'),
        ('FEMALE', 'female')
    ]
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='No bio data', max_length=400)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    gerder = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, default='NONE')
    country = CountryField()
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='avatars/')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True, related_name='friends')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, blank = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    favourite = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-{self.created}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        

    ```
````

Comment: when user.username changes, does the slug change as well?

Answer (score 2):

I like using Django Autoslug https://pypi.org/project/django-autoslug/

```
pip install django-autoslug
```

After install, make sure you import it in your models.py file

```py
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
```

Here is how the slug would look in your case:

```py
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
```